# Print function signature in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

I have a function:

```
fs.readFile = function(filename, callback) {
    // implementation code.
};
```

Sometime later I want to see the signature of the function during debugging.

When I tried `console.log(fs.readFile)` I get `[ FUNCTION ]`, which does not give me any information.

How can I get the signature of the function?

Comment: There are no types in javascript, so there is not much of a signature.

Comment: @Amberlamps Can i know the number of variables this function has, in its signature? Although we can pass as many as we want.

Comment: You can not read the signature ootb because of the missing types but I think this [SO-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833399/how-to-detect-a-javascript-function-with-a-certain-signature-has-been-registered) will help you to built a helper function to detect the signature.

Comment: @AshishNegi Are you using Node.js? See the documentation of `fs.readFile`: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback

Comment: `functionname.toString().match(/function\s*(.*?)\s*{/)[1]`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Call `.toString()` on the function:

```js
$ node
> foo = function(bar, baz) { /* some code */ }
[Function: foo]
> foo
[Function: foo]
> foo.toString()
'function(bar, baz) { /* some code */ }'
```

or use a shortcut like `foo+""`.

Answer (score 9):

If what you mean by "function signature" is how many arguments it has defined, you can use:

```
function fn (one) {}
console.log(fn.length); // 1
```

All functions get a length property automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you want but try looking at the console log of this fiddle, it prints entire function definition. I am looking at chrome console.log output.

```
var fs = fs || {};
fs.readFile = function(filename, callback) {
  alert(1);
};
console.log(fs.readFile);
```

[DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/K7DMA/](http://jsfiddle.net/K7DMA/)

Comment: You're right, code is available after calling toString() of the function object