# Console logging a Function in concat mode prints the function implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is a simple example

```
function foo() {
   const bar = '123';
   return bar;
}
```

And here is how console.log behaves and prints differently in NodeJS:

```
> console.log(foo)
[Function: foo]

> console.log("", foo)
 function foo() {
const bar = '123';
return bar;
}
```

Why is that? And is there a way to hide it, i.e. only get `[Function: foo]` printed.

The same similar behaviour happens in Chrome developer panel.

Comment: Which console are you asking about?

Comment: On Firefox I guess? On Chrome both print the function body.

Comment: Firefox prints `function foo()` in both cases for me. So maybe NodeJS?

Comment: screenshot please ?

Comment: Chrome : `ƒ foo() {  const bar = '123'; return bar;}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Print Function Signature in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022121/how-to-print-function-signature-in-javascript)

Comment: Yep this is NodeJS.

Comment: Why are you using `console.log("", foo)`? Why can't you just use your first example all the time if that generates the output you want?

Comment: @Andy Because this is an example. I'm interested to know why this is happening.

Comment: @FastSnail the code above is copy/paste from NodeJS panel. I can't imagine what a screenshot would reveal more.

Comment: In my chrome developer panel doesn't happen absolutely the same behavior you are describing.....btw, why you don't use `console.log('My pre text message ' + foo);` to avoid the issue it seems you are having?

Comment: @quirimmo because I'm interested to know why this is happening, not a practical code example

Comment: @Kousha which version of chrome are you using? if I do the same you say I absolutely don't see this behavior. On chrome I always have the function body as other people already said before

Comment: The "why" is just because that's how they designed their `console` to work.

Comment: @quirimmo I figured out the "issue". Posted it as an answer

Comment: @spanky I figured out what was causing this behavior. Basically `toString` is invoked.

Comment: @Kousha: Yes, that's how `toString()` represents a function, but I'm not sure what that has to do with your question.

Comment: @Kousha but can you please remove this from your question that is totally false: "The same similar behaviour happens in Chrome developer panel."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a bit more, I believe this is due to `toString` of the function. When you use `console.log("", foo)`, `console.log` stringifies all arguments and concats them, hence `foo.toString` is invoked.

You can see the same behaviour if you also do `console.log(foo.toString())`

As a further addition, you can replace `toString`:

```
function foo() {
   const bar = '123';
   return bar;
}

foo.toString = () => 'replaced';
```

and now you get (in NodeJS terminal):

```
> console.log(foo)
{ [Function: foo] toString: [Function] }
undefined
> console.log("", foo)
 replaced
undefined
> console.log(foo.toString())
replaced
```

Comment: Yes, it's clear that it's getting `toString()` called. Doesn't really answer why they decided to do it in one argument position instead of the other, does it?

Comment: @spanky yes it does. When you provide multiple arguments to console.log, it stringifies each argument and concats them.

Comment: Well, yes, but that doesn't explain why they chose to stringify in one argument position and not the other, other than to say that the two are different because they made them different.